# Updating a Primary Key Field with potential collision

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a primary key field that I need to update by multiplying by 10.

Currently my ids are:

```
`id`
- 1
- 2
- ...
- 10
- 11
- etc.
```

To do the update I tried:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE status SET id = id*10;
COMMIT;
```

However, I get a pk complaint (because 1*10 = 10, which is a current primary key).

How would I solve this issue and do this update?

**Update**: this is something that is required due to a legacy table that I need to update. I'm not looking for advice on db design, but literally how I would accomplish this update.

Comment: This is a bad idea. PK should be just *unique identifier* - nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply an ORDER BY statement on your update query:

```
UPDATE status SET id = id*10 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This should prevent any conflicts as the higher values are updated first.

Answer (score 3):

Your primary key should serve to uniquely identify each row... not to provide any type of ordering.  You shouldn't be trying to fit items between other items by manipulating your primary key.

Instead, consider adding an `OrderID` column to the table if you need to be able to hard-code arbitrary ordering for these rows.

Comment: Right, this was more updating legacy code that didn't have that additional column in the first place (and I had lots of entries that referenced the id as a FK).

Comment: @David542 Having *lots of entries that referenced the id as a FK* is another good reason to leave it alone.  Now you will need to change all these tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while we lack a more slick solution to your problem, you can

1. Create a temporary table with the same structure
2. Do an `INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT id*10, --all other fields`. This will not cause id collisions.
3. Remove all data from original table
4. Do and `INSERT INTO` back from the temp table to the original table

**Important:** Please make sure you do a backup before this.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion of how to fix this problem.